# Jasmine to spyon React component's methods

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component class with a couple of methods -

```
var testClass = React.createClass({
testMethod: function(){//do something
}
componentDidMount: function(){
    this.testMethod();
}
render: function() {
    ...
}
});
```

I am trying to add a unit test using jasmine

```
import TestClass from './testClass';

describe('test functions', () => {
'use strict';

 spyOn(TestClass.prototype, 'testMethod');
 it('test calls testMethod', () => {
    component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<TestClass />);
    expect(TestClass.prototype.testMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

I can see in the debugger that the testMethod is really getting called but jasmine reports "Expected spy testMethod to have been called."

Answer (score 0):

React v0.14.2, `createClass` maintains an object map of defined methods in [`__reactAutoBindMap`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v0.14.2/src/isomorphic/classic/class/ReactClass.js#L816) and reuses this map to rebind the methods to the component in the the private constructor for the component.

This behavior can be worked around in the tests by resetting this map to an empty object, forcing the constructor to skip this map and use the replacement spy.

```
function mockComponentMethod(component, method) {
   const boundMethod = method.bind(component)
   component.prototype.__reactAutoBindMap = {};
   component.prototype[method.name] = boundMethod;

   return boundMethod;
}
```

The test to check that the spy was called can be written as follows:

```
const testMethodSpy = spyOn(TestClass.prototype, 'testMethod');
mockComponentMethod(TestClass, testMethodSpy);
expect(testMethodSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```